# Citation missing

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I was using my LaTeX file without much trouble till I hit a point where I started getting citation missing errors (I get a (? ) in the preview pdf).

After a certain point in my BibTeX file I am facing this issue for any new citation that I add.  There are similar questions on TeX Stack Exchange but nothing that addressed my particular issue and hence I am posting it.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \setlength{\textheight}{9in}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{epigraph} % To have quotes at the begining

    \usepackage{graphicx}
```

I have the following bibliography request:

```
    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \bibliography{Networks_Final}
```

(Networks_Final.bib is my BibTeX file)

Image notes: "this is junk(? )" is the error. I tried citing something that I used previously used in the part where the output is "is is junk (1)" and it works.

The problem was resolved when I deleted `.aux`, `.bbl` and other files. But appeared again with the following entry:

```
    @article{schaefer2008us,
    title={How Do US Foreign Aid Recipients Vote at the UN? Against the US},
    author={Schaefer, Brett D and Kim, Anthony B},
    journal={Backgrounder},
    number={2171},
    year={2008}
}
```

Comment: when you run bibtex do you get any errors (what is in the .blg log file?)

Comment: Please add a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `acm` is designed to generate numeric-style citation call-outs. To get it to work with the `natbib` package, load `natbib` with the  option `numbers`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{acm}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Networks_Final.bib}
@article{schaefer2008us,
    title={How Do {US} Foreign Aid Recipients Vote at the {UN}? {Against} the {US}},
    author={Schaefer, Brett D and Kim, Anthony B},
    journal={Backgrounder},
    number={2171},
    year={2008}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Test.\cite{schaefer2008us}
\bibliography{Networks_Final}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of rephrasing the first para; feel free to revert.